# No entiendo como aplicar 'require_once' para MVC-POO-PHP

Tags: php, poo, mvc

Llevo varias semanas empapandome de todo lo que puedo sobre el MVC y la POO para PHP. Pero me encuentro en un punto que no se solucionar y no entiendo que está fallando.

Tengo una aplicación web en PHP con dos modelos. Cuando escribo el código de los modelos en el archivo vista, los crea correctamente. Pero para un mejor mantenimiento, quiero crear un fichero "intermedio" donde haga la llamada de todos los modelos (en un futuro serán más). Cuando utilizo el archivo intermedio no me arroja el resultado esperado y no entiendo porque.

Os pongo los dos fragmentos de código. El primero funciona, pero no es nada práctico:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    require_once 'config.php';

class DevuelveProductos extends Conexion{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_productos(){
        $resultado = $this->conexion_db->query('SELECT * FROM whch_class');
        $productos = $resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $productos;
    }
}

class DevuelveRaza extends Conexion{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_razas(){
        $resultado = $this->conexion_db->query('SELECT * FROM whch_race');
        $productos = $resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $productos;
    }
}

    $productos = new DevuelveProductos();
    $array_productos=$productos->get_productos();

    $raza= new DevuelveRaza();
    $array_raza=$raza->get_razas();
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello!</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
foreach($array_productos as $elemento){
    echo"<table><tr><td>";
    echo $elemento['Id_Clase']."</td><td>";
    echo $elemento['Clase']."</td><td>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}
foreach($array_raza as $elemento){
    echo"<table><tr><td>";
    echo $elemento['Raza']."</td><td>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

El segundo creo que sería el óptimo, pero cuando cargo la página en el navegador no me muestra las listas.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <?php
        require_once 'config.php';
        require_once 'productos.php';
        require_once 'raza.php';
//En los archivos productos.php y raza.php lo único que hago es copiar las dos clases y encerrarlas entre etiquetas <?php ?>

        $productos = new DevuelveProductos();
        $array_productos=$productos->get_productos();
    
        $raza= new DevuelveRaza();
        $array_raza=$raza->get_razas();
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <?php
    foreach($array_productos as $elemento){
        echo"<table><tr><td>";
        echo $elemento['Id_Clase']."</td><td>";
        echo $elemento['Clase']."</td><td>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";
    }
    foreach($array_raza as $elemento){
        echo"<table><tr><td>";
        echo $elemento['Raza']."</td><td>";
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

¿Alguien me puede orientar hacia lo que tengo que hacer? Gracias.

Comment: ¿y no te aparece ningún tipo de error en ninguna parte tampoco? Te sale al menos el Hello!?

Comment: El problema es que lo tuyo NO es MVC. ¿Por qué pones cosas de la Vista en esos archivos? ¿Esos archivos deben ser php puro, sin contenido HTML. MVC funciona así: El Controlador recibiría la petición con los datos de entrada si los hubiera, se los pediría al Modelo y luego procesaría esos datos y se los pasaría a la Vista para que los muestre. Es más simple de como lo estás imaginando / implementando.

Comment: @A.Cedano Se que no es puro MVC, estoy haciendo la transición y este ejercicio de separar las capas me ayuda a comprenderlo mejor.

Comment: @masterguru Acabo de volver a cargar el código y ahora funciona :(

Gracias a los dos por vuestro interés

Comment: Si te aparece una página en blanco (vacía) pero con error HTTP 500, significa que PHP está soltando un error que no está imprimiendo debido a tus reglas de configuración, te sugiero revisar los valores de tu php.ini corriendo `php --ini` para revelar la ubicación del archivo y tras abrirlo revisa las etiquetas  (llaves): `log_errors`, `error_log`, `display_errors`, etc…